# How to configure Evolution to use DavMail's LDAP contacts?

Tags: evolution, ldap, ms-exchange

My doubts are in the Authentication Section:

- Authentication Method ?!
- Session?

And I also don't know how to fill in the Details tab:

- Search base ?
- Search Scope ?
- Search filter ?

How should I fill these in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are instructions, adapted from http://davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirddirectorysetup.html. I successfully use these settings for my Exchange account.

1. In DavMail, configure your settings as recommended from http://davmail.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html. Note the port number that you use for `Local LDAP port` (e.g. 1389). You can use any port number you like that isn't already being used.

   [image: DavMail Gateway Settings]
2. In Evolution, select `File > New > Address Book`.
3. Configure your address book with the following settings:

   #### Address Book

   - Type: **On LDAP Servers**
   - Name: **Exchange** (or anything you want)

   #### Server Information

   - Server: **localhost** (or the address of your DavMail server)
   - Port: **1389** (or the port specified in your DavMail settings)
   - Use secure connection: **No encryption** (if you're running DavMail locally or didn't enable encryption in your DavMail settings) or **SSL encryption** (if enabled)

   #### Authentication

   - Login method: **Using distinguished name (DN)**
   - Login: (your Exchange username)

   [image: New Address Book - General]

   #### Searching

   - Search base: **ou=people**

   [image: New Address Book - Details]
4. Configure other address book settings to your liking.