# Gnome Evolution Contacts over DavMail to an Micrsoft Exchange with autehtication does not work

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange, davmail

The problem is that my **Contacts** are stored in an **Exchange 2007 Server** which *needs authentication on login*.

But the *Auth data* is not passed through DavMail to Exchange. (Checked with WireShark.)

Is there a fix to get Evolution and DavMail Combo to send the login to the Exchange?

Thunderbird/DavMail Contacts do work.

The settings in Evolution and DavMail  are like mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30914/how-to-configure-evolution-to-use-davmails-ldap-contacts).